# c# JQuery datatable checked/unchecked rows

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a table that uses datatable and select plugins, i am able to get the data of all those selected rows and store it in hidden field to be able to access in my code behind. Now, i want CHECKED/UNCHECKED rows from my datatable based on the parameters i have.. Do you have a sample code that i can use as a reference?

This is how i initialized my datatable and how i store the selected rows in hidden field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#contactDataTable').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets: 0
        }],

        select: {
            style: 'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]],
        pageLength: 5
    });

$('#btnGetSelectedRows').on('click', function () {
        var dataArr = [];
        let rows = table.rows({ selected: true });
        var result = table.cells(rows.nodes(), 2).data();
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            dataArr.push(result[i]);
        }             
        console.log(dataArr);
        //$("#hdnSelectedContacts").val(dataArr);    This will set the value to asp hidden field            
    });
```

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your server renders the CSS class `selected` on all `tr` that should be checked. Then, after initializing your table, execute this on the datatables instance which you stored in `table`:

```
 // make sure pre-selected rows are known to datatables.net-select
 table.rows('.selected').select();
```